# Redirection to stderr works in bash, not in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe, io-redirection, file-descriptors

In bash,

```bsh
❯ echo "hello" 1>&2 | echo "world"
hello
world
```

In zsh,

```bsh
❯ echo "hello" 1>&2 | echo "world"
world
```

More than a way around this, I am trying to understand why does this happen? What is the mechanism in play here.

Answer (score 6):

That seems to have something to do with how zsh implements MULTIOS, i.e. the feature where it allows multiple redirections. If you run e.g.

```
echo hello > abc > def
```

it duplicates the output to both files by turning it internally into something like:

```
echo hello | tee abc def >/dev/null
```

Doing

```
echo "hello" 1>&2 | echo "world"
```

is then similar to

```
echo "hello" | tee /dev/stderr | echo "world"
```

and that actually only prints `world` even in Bash with the `tee` from GNU coreuitls. On my Debian system anyway. Most of the time. The thing to note here is that `echo` doesn't read any input, and probably exits quickly, faster than `tee` can get input from the left-hand pipe and write it to the other one. Then, when `tee` gets around to writing to the pipe, it gets SIGPIPE and dies. But that's a race.

That is, the sequence of events is something like this:

- both the `echo`'s print what ever they print, and both exit
- `tee` reads `hello` and tries to write to the pipe
- it gets SIGPIPE and exits.

This depends on the order the processes get scheduled, if both the left-hand `echo` and the `tee` get to run before the  right-hand `echo`, there's no issue. It also depends on `tee` writing to the pipe first, but that's what seems to happen with both the GNU version of `tee` and with the zsh I have.

Checking with `strace` we see the `tee` writes to fd 1 first and dies:

```
$ echo "hello" | strace tee /dev/stderr | echo "world"
...
open("/dev/stderr", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
read(0, "hello\n", 8192)                = 6
write(1, "hello\n", 6)                  = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=20498, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

Similarly with zsh. It's harder to trace just the correct process here, and tracing the whole shell gives the system calls of all the involved processes, interleaved. Anyway, there's the one process that reads the `hello`, and then immediately tries to write it somewhere, getting a SIGPIPE.

```
$ strace -f zsh -c 'echo "hello" 1>&2 | echo "world"'
...
[pid 20503] read(14, "hello\n", 4092)   = 6
[pid 20503] write(13, "hello\n", 6)     = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
[pid 20503] --- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=20503, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 20503] +++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

---

On macOS, the above pipeline with `tee /dev/stderr` gives me both `hello` and `world`, but e.g. this loses the second output line:

```
$ (echo abc; sleep 2; echo def) | tee /dev/stderr | false
abc
```

That's consistent with this `tee` writing to `/dev/stderr` first, then dying of the failure to write to the pipe and then being unable to write the second line. But I don't know if there's an equivalent of `strace` there to see the details with.

And here, the first line goes through without obstructions since `read` reads it, but the second is again missing:

```
$ zsh -c '(echo abc; sleep 2; echo def) 1>&2 | read'
abc
```

---

The GNU man page for `tee` also mentions that `tee` exits on error on pipe write:

> The default operation when `--output-error` is not specified, is to exit immediately on error writing to a pipe, and diagnose
> errors writing to non pipe outputs.

With the option set, it ignores SIGPIPE, gets over the error and continues:

```
$ echo "hello" | tee --output-error=warn /dev/stderr | echo "world"
world
tee: 'standard output': Broken pipe
hello
```

On the other hand, Busybox's `tee` appears to just ignore SIGPIPE and the error:

```
$ echo "hello" | strace busybox tee /dev/stderr | echo "world"
world
...
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x412030}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/stderr", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
read(0, "hello\n", 1024)                = 6
write(1, "hello\n", 6)                  = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=11700, si_uid=1000} ---
write(3, "hello\n", 6hello
)                  = 6
read(0, "", 1024)                       = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

---

In any case, piping to something that doesn't read any input is probably a bit silly. Something like this would run the two `echo`s independently:

```
echo "hello" 1>&2 & echo "world"
```

Comment: Ah, I have the latest stable release of bash on macOS (installed via home brew), and it prints both “hello” & “world”

Comment: Also, I know it’s a “silly” formulation & that’s deliberate. I wanted to see what happens when I have a command in pipe that doesn’t consume from pipe.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I wonder why such important examples are not covered in any book... or is there one that you would know of that covers io redirection/pipes/multios in depth? On macOS there is ``dtruss`` alternative to ``strace``, though am pretty new to this world, will give it a try soon.

Comment: Also, macOS's ``/usr/bin/tee`` does not provide ``--output-error`` option. I had to install use gnu tee ``gtee`` available in bottle ``coreutils``. Installation steps for all gnu stuff is mentioned there: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332/433973

Comment: @reportaman, I wonder, what the real-world use would be for `tee` in a pipeline where the right-hand side can exit early. One could have something like `blah... | tee outfile | grep -q keyword`, but would anyone do that instead of `blah... > outfile; grep -q keyword outfile` (the former might be better for caching locality though). If zsh hasn't documented it, then that's a bit odd. [POSIX only says `tee` must continue if writes to _files_ give errors.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/tee.html)

Comment: If I use gnu coreutil's gecho, and gtee, both "hello" and "world" get printed. ``gecho "hello" | gtee /dev/stderr | gecho "world"``. ``brew install coreutils``. Any idea why would that be so?

Comment: dtruss seems to affect the output of pipe, I asked another question based on your usage of strace: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/673293/456507

Comment: busybox's tee does not ignore the sigpipe signal. those strace examples are irrelevant because they rely on timing.

Comment: @UncleBilly, they show which order the program in question writes to the two outputs. If the pipe is closed at that point depends on the timing, yes, that's why I wrote it's a race. And yes, running a tracer on `tee` probably influences the timing, so that there's a higher chance that the pipe is already closed when `tee` writes to it. But we have here examples of systems where that happens even without tracing.

Comment: The Busyboxes I tested with (1.22.1 and 1.30.1) at least don't get terminated by SIGPIPE. E.g. running `echo "hello" | tee /dev/stderr | echo "world";` on Debian/Ubuntu gives just `world` and Bash's `PIPESTATUS` contains `0 141 0`, showing the signal. But with `busybox tee` instead, both get printed and `PIPESTATUS` shows zeroes.

Comment: ...and of course doing e.g. `echo "hello" | tee /dev/stderr | (sleep 1; echo "world")` gives a different result (though it's still possible in principle that it takes more than a second for the two right-hand processes to get to the point where `tee` writes to the second pipe)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it seems that busybox used to ignore the SIGPIPE [**in older versions**](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/coreutils/tee.c?id=427c12cc5199813328bf7fdf0bc4fc3a7672bf0f). But the output of strace still relies on the order in which the kernel schedules random processes, and so it's irrelevant.

Comment: @UncleBilly, sigh. No, it's not irrelevant. It shows the **order in which the writes are done by tee**, which affects what happens if it gets the SIGPIPE. It doesn't tell everything about if and when it does get it, but it does explain what happens next.