# Closing stdout fd gives error, while closing stderr fd does not

Tags: zsh, pipe, io-redirection, file-descriptors

The following test code gives error "bad file descriptor". Why is that so? This is just a test code to understand file descriptors and their interaction with pipes.

Example 1)

```bsh
❯ echo "hello" 1>&2 1>&- |& echo "world"
world
zsh: 1: bad file descriptor
```

Example 2)

```bsh
echo "hello" 1>&2 1>&- | cat <<< "world"
zsh: write error: bad file descriptor
world
```

Example 3)

```bsh
# Does not give error
❯ echo "helloworld" >&-
# Gives stdin? error
❯ cat <<< "helloworld" >&-
cat: stdin: Bad file descriptor
```

If I were to close just stderr, or both stdout and stderr, then I do not receive the "bad file descriptor" error. For instance, neither of following give that error:

```bsh
❯ echo "hello" 1>&2 2>&- |& echo "world"
❯ echo "hello" 2>&1 2>&- |& echo "world"
❯ echo "hello" 1>&2 1>&- 2>&- |& echo "world"
```

Comment: Where would the error message be written  if `STDERR` is closed?

Comment: @waltinator This question is to understand how things work, I won't be using a pipe in exactly this manner. I want to understand why I get error "bad file descriptor", it would give me some more insight in pipes and redirection.

Answer (score 1):

`|&` is a shorthand for `2>&1 |` (as [documented](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Simple-Commands-_0026-Pipelines)). The standard output of the left-hand side is connected to the write side of the pipe before performing other redirections¹, but the standard error is connected at the end, to whatever the standard output is at the time. This makes a difference if standard output is redirected, or, as in your example, closed. With `foo 1>&- |& bar`, or with the equivalent `foo 1>&- 2>&1 | bar`, or for that matter with just `foo 1>&- 2>&1`, there's nothing on file descriptor 1 at the time the redirection of fd 2 to fd 1 is applied.

With `foo 1>&2 1>&- | bar`, first the standard output of `foo` is connected to the write side of the pipe, then (assuming `multios` is on) `1>&2` creates a pipe to a built-in tee-like process which will write both to the pipe created by the `|` operator and to what is on file descriptor 2 at the time (which is the terminal). Then `1>&-` closes stdout, so if `foo` ever tries to write to stdout, this write will fail. It doesn't matter how many places the tee-like process is writing to: after `1>&-` there's no way it can receive any input.

¹  <sub>I can't find this specified in the documentation, but that's what shells traditionally do and it is [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02). If you're unsure, you can check the source code, a system call trace, or you can deduce it from the outcome of various experiments with redirection such as the ones you've been making.</sub>

Comment: How about the error for example 2) ``echo "hello" 1>&2 1>&- | cat <<< "world"``. In that I redirect the "hello" to stderr, and close stdout. I don't see it being printed in stderr, and still has that error.

Comment: Also, what's the source of "The standard output of the left-hand side is connected to the write side of the pipe before performing other redirections, but the standard error is connected at the end, to whatever the standard output is at the time."? The reason I ask is, in ``zsh`` with default multios enabled, each additional 1>&1 doubles the number of lines printed. For instance this will print the same contents 8 times: ``ls -lrta 1>&1 1>&1 1>&1 | cat``.

Comment: @reportaman Example 2 is a minor variant. `1>&-` closes stdout. Whatever tries to write to stdout after that, or to duplicate stdout to another file descriptor, will fail. The fact that the pipe is applied first is independent of the effect of multios. In terms of redirections (but not in terms of process hierarchy), `foo >qux | bar` is equivalent to `foo >(bar) >qux`.

Comment: I have added an example 3, it makes me wonder why ``echo`` does not give error while ``cat`` does.

Comment: @zevzek Where did hello disappear in ``echo "hello" 1>&2 1>/dev/null | echo "world"`` or even ``echo "hello" 1>&2 | echo "world"``. In zsh it prints only world. Someone replied to my question regarding that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/672939/456507