# Why does redirection cause output to be duplicated?

Tags: zsh, io-redirection

In zsh, why does

```bsh
echo hi >&2 | cat
```

produce the output

```
hi
hi
```

?

My understanding is

1. `>&2` causes `dup2(STDERR_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO)` to be called.
2. `| cat` causes `dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO)` to be called, where `fd` is the write-end of a pipe which gets fed into the `cat` process.

Step 2 overrides step 1 and, therefore, it's as if step 1 never happened.  Clearly, my understanding is wrong.  Why does this command not produce the same output as

```bsh
echo hi | cat
```

?

For context, this is zsh 5.8.  I don't see this behavior in bash.

Comment: Getting just a single `hi` in 4.4.23. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Seing OP's behaviour in 5.8.1

Comment: A somewhat extended explanation, here on U&L (which also points to the relevant documentation): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673270/315749

Comment: Also, the pipe is set up before the redirections, hence, assuming multios isn't in effect, `>&2` would override `| cat`. Try, for instance, `setopt nomultios; echo hi >&2 | sed 's/$/!/'`

Comment: On zsh 4.8.1 on Fedora 35 and seeing same thing as OP. @fra-san, can't speak for OP but if you submit that as an answer, I'll upvote it. Tried `setopt nomultios; echo hi 2>&1 | cat` and I get a single 'hi', just as one would expect from the equivalent bash statement.